# Split string to different elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have xml with text element with substring which can be matched by pattern `§\d+`:

```
<root>
  <item>text-one §42 text-two</item>
</root>
```

Is it possible to transofrm it with xslt-1.0 to separated elements:

```
<p>
  <xsl:text>text-one </xsl:text>
  <a href="/link#42>§42</a>
  <xsl:text> text-two</xsl:text>
</p>
```

Comment: If you really want to use regular expression based matching or splitting then check whether your used XSLT 1 processor supports that via extension functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet does what you want, as long as

- a whitespace is ok as end-delimiter for the paragraph number

  ```
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <root>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="root/*"/>
      </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
      <p>
          <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
              <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize">
      <xsl:param name="text"/>
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="contains($text, '§')">
              <xsl:if test="substring-before($text, '§') != ''">
                  <text><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '§')"/></text>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:call-template name="buildParagraphAnchor">
                  <xsl:with-param name="tail" select="substring-after($text, '§')"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
              <text><xsl:value-of select="$text"/></text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="buildParagraphAnchor">
      <xsl:param name="tail"/>
      <xsl:variable name="paragraphNumber">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="contains($tail, ' ')">
                  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($tail, ' ')"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$tail"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <a href="/link#{$paragraphNumber}"><xsl:text>§</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$paragraphNumber"/></a>
      <xsl:if test="contains($tail, ' ')">
          <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
              <xsl:with-param name="text" select="concat(' ', substring-after($tail, ' '))"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  ```

It transforms

```
<root>
    <item>text-one §42 text-two §45</item>
    <item>§50 text-three</item>
    <item>text-four</item>
</root>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <p>
        <text>text-one </text>
        <a href="/link#42">§42</a>
        <text> text-two </text>
        <a href="/link#45">§45</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="/link#50">§50</a>
        <text> text-three</text>
    </p>
    <p>
        <text>text-four</text>
    </p>
</root>
```

- The two templates call each other recursively (very typical for XSL)
- The `tokenize` template splits the content based on the paragraph symbol into head and tail (before/after the symbol)
- The `buildParagraphAnchor` splits the tail again into head and tail based on a whitespace
- This way we are able to put the chunks into the correct elements
- The rest is special handling when the paragraph symbol is the first character etc

So it splits the `item`content in chunks and puts the parts into the needed elements.